# Not able to implement data from one api used to get data from another

Tags: reactjs

I am making a meme sharing app. In that app there are total 2 apis of getting memes.
One for memes by all the users another is only for individual user.
In second api I am able to get the data as the user id is from 3rd api.
from here i get the id of each individual.

```
function UserProfile({memeid}) {
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
const [id, setId] = useState('')
const userData = async() => {
  await axios
    .get("http://localhost:8081/userInfo/me", {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
     })
    .then((res) => {
      setResponse(res.data)
      setId(res.data.id)
      memeid = id
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })

}
console.log(id)
useEffect(()=>{
  userData()
},[])
```

Now I want this to be used in in another api. for that is have written this code.

```
function MemeById({id}) {

const [response, setResponse] = useState([])
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

// const id = "632a119672ba0e4324b18c7d"

const memes = async () => {
  await axios
    .get("http://localhost:8081/memes/" + id, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    })
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      setResponse(res.data)
      console.log(data);
    })
     .catch((err) => {
      alert(err);
      console.log(err);
    });
};

useEffect(()=>{
  memes()
},[])
```

I am calling these two at User

```
function User() {

let id;


return (
  <div>
    <UserProfile memeid={id}/>
    <MemeById id = {id}  />
  </div>
)
```

}

I am getting the error for this.
How to solve this error

Comment: what's the error which you're getting? did you check the value of the id is coming or not?

Comment: error is Request failed with status code 404 id is getting as undefined

Comment: can you please add the entire flow from where <MemeById > was calling? please update the question

Comment: and there is no need of calling API until the id is available just add that condition in useEffect()... you can do -> useEffect(() => if(!id) return; memes())

Comment: Still not able to get memes

Answer (score 1):

You're making a big mistake. I think you should learn more about state and props in react.

Problem :

In your User component, you're creating a variable and passing that variable into two other component. You're trying to update the value of props from UserProfile and expecting that updated value in MemeById which is not going to work.

Solution :

```
function User() {
    const [memeId, setMemeId] = useState(null);

    return (
    <div>
        <UserProfile updateId={(newId) => setMemeId(newId)}/>
        <MemeById memeId = {memeId}  />
    </div>
    )
}
```

And in your UserProfile component

```
function UserProfile({updateId}) {
...
const userData = async() => {
    ...
    // memeid = id
    updateId(res.data.id)
    ...
}
```

In you MemeById component:

```
function MemeById({memeId}) {
    ...
    // use memeId here
    ...
}
```